# For range iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to iterate a certain number of lines from a text file. I've tried doing so by using different combinations of `i += 1` and `for` loops, but it just seems to print out all of the lines from the text file.

```
def showEntries(amount):
    print("---------- SUBSCRIPTIONS ----------\n")
    with open('lib/names.txt','r') as names:
        for line in names:
            for x in range(0,2):
                print(line)
    print("----------  END OF LIST  ----------")
```

Comment: What output are you expecting

Comment: @Anmol_uppal Three lines of the text file where print(line) is in a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
for line_no, line in enumerate(names):
    if line_no >= amount:  # if we've seen enough already
        break  # stop looping
    print(line)  # otherwise show the current line
```

For example:

```
>>> names = ["John Cleese", "Graham Chapman", "Terry Gilliam", "Eric Idle", "Terry Jones", "Michael Palin"]
>>> for index, name in enumerate(names):
    if index >= 3:
        break
    print(name)


John Cleese
Graham Chapman
Terry Gilliam
```

See [the docs on `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for this.

```
from itertools import islice

def showEntries(filename, amount):

    with open(filename,'r') as names:
        for line in islice(names, amount):
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want to do ...

a. Get an email address as input from the user and add it to a file. As an aside ... you may want to do the following before you write it to the file...
 - ensure that the email address is a valid address (use regex to enforce this)
 - ensure that the email address does not exist already (you don't want a file full of duplicate addresses)
etc...

and,
b. Print out how a specified number of results from your subscriber list. You need to either put your

Here's a quick example of what you can do to read x number of lines from. I've used a lot of syntactic sugar .. which you can choose not to use..

```
def printLines(numlines):
    i = 0
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if i < numlines:
                print line
                i += 1
            else:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really close — you just need to let the iteration of the number of lines control the loop, not the number of them in the file:

```
def showEntries(amount):
    print("---------- SUBSCRIPTIONS ----------\n")
    with open('lib/names.txt', 'r') as names:
        for _ in range(amount):
            print(next(file).rstrip())
    print("----------  END OF LIST  ----------")
```

To be more robust, inner portion of the loop probably should be wrapped in a `try/except` to handle the case were the file contains less than the specified number of lines gracefully.